# expected string or bytes-like object　原因不明なエラー

Tags: python, lambda

lambda で以下のエラーが起きています。pythonコードも記載しました。
原因不明で助けて頂きたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
{
  "errorMessage": "expected string or bytes-like object",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 30, in lambda_handler\n    client = gspread.authorize(creds)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/gspread/__init__.py\", line 38, in authorize\n    client.login()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/gspread/client.py\", line 51, in login\n    self.auth.refresh(http)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/oauth2client/client.py\", line 545, in refresh\n    self._refresh(http)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/oauth2client/client.py\", line 749, in _refresh\n    self._do_refresh_request(http)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/oauth2client/client.py\", line 778, in _do_refresh_request\n    resp, content = transport.request(\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/oauth2client/transport.py\", line 280, in request\n    return http_callable(uri, method=method, body=body, headers=headers,\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/httplib2/__init__.py\", line 1765, in request\n    (scheme, authority, request_uri, defrag_uri) = urlnorm(uri)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/httplib2/__init__.py\", line 234, in urlnorm\n    (scheme, authority, path, query, fragment) = parse_uri(uri)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/httplib2/__init__.py\", line 229, in parse_uri\n    groups = URI.match(uri).groups()\n"
  ]
}
```

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    keys = create_keyfile_dict()
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(keys, scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    
    # Google Sheetsのスプレッドシートを開く
    spreadsheet_key = os.environ['SHEET_ID']
    workbook = client.open_by_key(spreadsheet_key)
    worksheet = workbook.worksheet(os.environ['SHEET_NAME'])
    
    
    # Google Sheetsからデータを取得
    resultsList = sheet.get_all_values()
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive APIのスコープを使用してるように見受けられるけれど
[Drive API スコープ](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/api-specific-auth?hl=ja) の一覧見ても `'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'` などは存在しません
古いのではないですか？

[Sheets API v3 からの移行](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration?hl=ja) によると, 以下が記されています

> **重要**: Google Sheets API v3 は 2021 年 8 月 2 日をもって終了しました。このガイドを使用して、Sheets API v4 に移行してください。

ちょうど V3 APIが, `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds` などのようです
Sheets API v4 に移行すべきでしょう

---

**追記**

> scopeの箇所を以下に変更してみましたが、相変わらずエラーが出ますね。。。

まず 普通に, 「認証してアクセス」までを試してみてはどうでしょう？ (以下を参照のこと)
AWS Lambda使うにしても, それができてからでよいでしょう

また「エラーが出る」ではなく, 詳細を示さないと対処難しいかも

参考: gspread (gspread.org) [Authentication](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！
scopeの箇所を以下に変更してみましたが、相変わらずエラーが出ますね。。。
｀scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']｀